# Mongodb $project: exclude all but one field of a subdocument, keep the rest

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with the following structure:

```
{
  field1: 1
  field2: 2
  subdocument: {
    subfield1: 3
    subfield2: 4
    subfield3: 5
    ...
  }
}
```

I would like to `$project` (or another operator if $project cannot do that?) so as to get:

1. all the top-level fields (field1, field2) **without having to list them explicitly**
2. only one of the subfields

The expected result would be:

```
{
  field1: 1
  field2: 2
  subdocument: {
    subfield1: 3
  }
}
```

I first thought I would look for a way to apply a `$project: {subfield1: 0}` only on the subdocument but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@SuleymanSah, 1 step with [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            "subdocument": {
              subfield1: "$subdocument.subfield1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/awx6mcQyuZO)

Comment: Ah I saw your previous solution with 2 steps and found it hard to read for someone not familiar with the goal, but this one seems clearer on the intent. That'll be my accepted answer!

Comment: @FlorentinHennecker Yes, you right, I've merged 2 steps into 1. `$replaceRoot` allow you change top-level document to new one and accepts `Expression`, so we can omit `$project` stage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly solution, but does the job.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "temp": "$subdocument.subfield1"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "subdocument": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "subdocument.subfield1": "$temp"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "temp": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tx0elDgi4zt)

I am interested a simpler solution.

Comment: @Valijon yep that also works, but I still think a simpler solution exists. I would upvote your answer, if my daily upvote limit hadn't been reached.